# Creating a dedicated android device for my daughter, Custom Rom ideas?

Tags: custom-roms, parental-control

New to this whole android game and needing some advice/help.

I want to set my old galaxy note 4 up for my younger daughter. I want to install a Custom Rom on it that will allow me to set up a handful of “default apps” (Talk, Text, Spotify, Kindle or Overdrive, clock, calculator, notes, and a couple of Games) but also remove the play store so no other apps can be downloaded and remove any browsers.

Is there a custom rom out there that can support this? Also... if play store is not on the phone how will updates work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't a site to recommend different ROMs, because recommendation questions tend to be opinion-based, but if you're interested in **how** to lock down a device this way, and the answer might not be a custom ROM, then that's a problem we can help you with. Please [edit] your question if you're happy with other solutions.

Comment: @DanHulme wouldn't a custom rom be the only way to lock it down? Otherwise a factor reset would just remove anything that makes it locked down. (of course using googles newer security changes some things about a factory reset but still)

Comment: Thanks for the responses, sorry for being the dumb new guy haha.  The reason i asked about custom roms is because i did a bunch of research and that was the only solution i could find... however i don’t know how those work and what all the different kinds are, hence my question. I apologize if I’m off topic.

Comment: @LateralTerminal (and to OP too) You can always just root then move apps into / remove apps from `/system` - untouched by factory reset, and will save the hassle of figuring out custom ROMs.

Comment: @RyanF I still don't think it's totally off topic. But it will be until you update what Note 4 you have. Give us exact model number. You know the carrier, att, tmobile? Don't forget give us the android version!!! I can't give you a suggestion without that info. (Because I know custom roms for that phone)

Comment: This also may be possible with [Parental Controls in Android](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1075738?hl=en)